# How to select MAX/MIN in MySQL with dynamic between clause

Tags: mysql, sql

Assume a table with two columns **t** (a string with TimeStamps) and **v** (decimal). For each **t** I want to query the **MAXIMUM** of the value **v** in a certain range defined by the current **t**.

How can i transfer below statement to proper SQL?

```
select t, max(v for t between t-2MIN and t+2min) from table_name;
```

**Example:**

Assume below table.

| t | v |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 5 |
| 4 | 4 |
| 5 | 8 |
| 6 | 1 |

I need an SQL-statement which gives me (for e.g. a width **2**: `max(v for t between t-2 and t+2)`) the following result

| t | v |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 |
| 2 | 5 |
| 3 | 8 |
| 4 | 8 |
| 5 | 8 |
| 6 | 8 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Join the table with itself using the range as the joining condition.

```
SELECT t1.t, MAX(t2.v) AS max_v
FROM table_name AS t1
JOIN table_name AS t2 ON t2.t BETWEEN t1.t - 2 AND t1.t + 2
GROUP BY t1.t
```

If you use MySQL 8.x I think you should be able to do it using window functions, but I don't know the proper syntax for this.

Comment: This worked, but its horribly slow. I now work with a syntax like:
SELECT
(GREATEST(COALESCE(table_name_0.value_1,-10000), COALESCE(table_name_1.value_1,-10000), ...)) AS greatest_value_1,
(GREATEST(COALESCE(table_name_0.value_2,-10000), COALESCE(table_name_2.value_2,-10000), ...)) AS greatest_value_2,
...
FROM table_name
LEFT JOIN table_name AS table_name_0 on TIMESTAMP(table_name_0.TS_V) = TIMESTAMP(STOCK_AV_AAPL.TS_V) - INTERVAL 0 MINUTE
LEFT JOIN table_name AS table_name_1 on TIMESTAMP(table_name_1.TS_V) = TIMESTAMP(STOCK_AV_AAPL.TS_V) - INTERVAL 1 MINUTE
...

Answer (score 0):

In MySql 8 you can use a `MAX OVER` with rows between a range.

```
select t
, max(v) over (order by t rows 
               between 2 preceding and 2 following) v
from table_name
```